# Как в обработчике события у chrome появляется event?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, frontend

Заметил, что если в браузере chrome выполнить вот такой код:

```
   document.body.addEventListener("click", ()=>{console.log(event.target);})
```

То он выполнится нормально, так, будто у стрелочной функции есть параметр event. Но ведь в реальности мы его не указывали. Подскажите пожалуйста, откуда в хроме в обработчике события берётся параметр event?

*В других браузерах такого не происходит, и этот код выдаст ошибку т.к. не передаётся event, но в хроме ошибки не происходит, и event.target реально печатается, мне просто интересно из-за чего это происходит.*

Comment: Хотя похоже сам разобрался, в хроме видимо есть глобальный window.event

Comment: На enSO есть [такой ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30159029/3432401) касательно этого дела